# How can I compress cipher output?

Tags: python, encryption

I have created my own cipher, but the problem with it is that its outputs may be very long. For example letter "i" would be

```
 6,6\,-5,-1,6,-5,-2,4,0,-3,0,3,0,-3,0,5,-4,0,0,2,0,-2,0,4
```

and word "cipher" would be

```
36,2\,0,0,0,1,0,4,-5,11,0,1,5,-4,0,6,4,0,3,3,0,0,1,0,-33,1,3,-2,6,-8,12,0,0,4,2,-6,10,2,-21,10,17,-21,25,-34,0,2,-2,10,-8,0,10,-9,13,3,3,0,0,4,0,1,5,-25,0,27,-34,1,-1,1,7,0,0,5,3,-3,5,-9,13,2,-8,0,0,16,0,1,0,-33,0,0,4,-2,6,0,0,4,-10,-2,18,-6,10,2,-12,-1,19,5,-4,-28,0,0,-2,3,4,-7,11,-4,0,12,-2,6,2,0,0,3,3,-3,0,5,-31.
```

This cipher can encode same message differently, but decode is always correct, for example, letter "i" can also be

```
6,4\,-3,1,1,0,-3,0,6,-5,-1,6,-5,1,2,-3,-1,5,-4,-1,5.
```

Can someone please suggest any method to make these outputs smaller? You can give me just an idea (I can code it myself) or give me python code. (I don't want to give cipher code, because I want to keep it private)

I have thought a lot about what can I do, but I couldn't come up with any good idea. Also, I have tried to use the zlib module, but it didn't give me good results. As I said before I am trying to make these outputs smaller. (If it's needed I can give some more sample outputs)

Comment: A cipher where the code has to be kept private isn't very useful.  One leak, and you're dead.  We can't talk about compression without knowing the possible range of the values.

Comment: If it helps, I can tell a little bit about what can output look like. The first two numbers are "settings", where 1st number is the length of the message times 6, the second number is somewhere in the range of -1, and 1st number. The rest of the output is some numbers separated by ",". These numbers can be in the range of -1st number and first number. And don't worry about code leaks, me and my friends can keep secrets.

Comment: You can use the same kind of tech that JPEG uses to turn this into a bitstream.  Most of your numbers are small, so focus on encoding those into the smaller number of bits.  However, it's clear that you didn't think about space efficiency when you designed this algorithm.  You might go back and think about that.

Comment: It is generally better to compress the plaintext first, and then encrypt the compressed file if you want a shorter cyphertext. Using a stream cipher will likely reduce the size of your cyphertext as well. Do *not* use you own cypher for anything that needs to be secure, just use it for practice or for fun.

Comment: If you've created a symmetric cipher that expands the plaintext then you're created something that's not useful. You can compress data that has a certain structure, but that structure is exactly what you're keeping from us.

Comment: Thank you all, I have managed to compress these outputs to 70% and I am still working on compressing better.